# canvas mouse pointer not synced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm currently learning canvas touch event function,I want to draw lines within the box,but the drawing not synced with mouse pointer.please help to check my codes and point out the mistake that I had made . thank You!

here is the coding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<style>
#contain {
width: 500px;
height: 120px;
top : 15px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;    
}
</style>
<script>
      var canvas;
      var ctx;
      var lastPt=null;
      var letsdraw = false;

    function init() {
        var touchzone = document.getElementById("layer1");
        touchzone.addEventListener("touchmove", draw, false);
        touchzone.addEventListener("touchend", end, false);
        ctx = touchzone.getContext("2d");
      }

    function draw(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(lastPt!=null) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(lastPt.x, lastPt.y);
          ctx.lineTo(e.touches[0].pageX, e.touches[0].pageY);
          ctx.stroke();
        }
        lastPt = {x:e.touches[0].pageX, y:e.touches[0].pageY};
      }

    function end(e) {
          var touchzone = document.getElementById("layer1");
        e.preventDefault();
        // Terminate touch path
        lastPt=null;
      }
    function clear_canvas_width ()
        {
            var s = document.getElementById ("layer1");
            var w = s.width;
            s.width = 10;
            s.width = w;
        }
    </script>    
</head>

<body onload="init()">

<div id="contain">
<canvas id="layer1" width="450" height="440" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;z-index:0; border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas> 
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to check for the element offset

Comment: What is the error, you face? Please consider using http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments try using an offset. ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rrJtR/))

If you have chrome, go to developers tab -> settings-> override -> Enable touch events to test the touch events in above demo fiddle.

```
  var canvas;
  var ctx;
  var lastPt = null;
  var letsdraw = false;
  var offX = 10, offY = 20;


  function init() {
      var touchzone = document.getElementById("layer1");
      touchzone.addEventListener("touchmove", draw, false);
      touchzone.addEventListener("touchend", end, false);
      ctx = touchzone.getContext("2d");
  }

  function draw(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (lastPt != null) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(lastPt.x, lastPt.y);
          ctx.lineTo(e.touches[0].pageX - offX,
                     e.touches[0].pageY - offY);
          ctx.stroke();
      }
      lastPt = {
          x: e.touches[0].pageX - offX,
          y: e.touches[0].pageY - offY
      };
  }

  function end(e) {
      var touchzone = document.getElementById("layer1");
      e.preventDefault();
      // Terminate touch path
      lastPt = null;
  }

  function clear_canvas_width() {
      var s = document.getElementById("layer1");
      var w = s.width;
      s.width = 10;
      s.width = w;
  }
```

Comment: But when I use google chrome to open the html file, canvas mouse pointer still not synced? may I know why? I only can draw lines when mouse point at the left side.

Comment: Did you see the demo?

Comment: Yes. I save the code as HTML file and open with chrome but when it come to full screen size. The mouse pointer still not synced. Thank you

Comment: Try changing the offX & offY values to make it sync as per the browser size.